# Merging two data frames in R and append a column

Tags: r

I 'm merging two data frames using `rbind`

```
 c1 <- c("a",1)
 c2 <- c("b",2)
 df <- data.frame(c1,c2)

 df1 <- data.frame(c1,c2)
 Net <- rbind(df,df1)
```

I would like to add an additional column that can distinguish the data from df and df1.
The desired output is,

```
 > Net
  c1 c2  c3
1  a  b  set1
2  1  2  set1
3  a  b  set2
4  1  2  set2
```

I can manually create a list and use `cbind` to append the column to `Net`. But, I would like to ask for suggestions on better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option with `data.table` is `rbindlist`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(df, df1), idcol = 'c3')[, c3:= paste0('set', c3)][]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bind_rows` w/ `.id =`

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

c1 <- c("a",1)
c2 <- c("b",2)
df <- data.frame(c1, c2)
df1 <- data.frame(c1, c2)

Net <- bind_rows(df, df1, .id = 'set')
Net
#>   set c1 c2
#> 1   1  a  b
#> 2   1  1  2
#> 3   2  a  b
#> 4   2  1  2
```

Then use `mutate_at` to change rows value

```r
Net %>% 
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(starts_with("set")), 
            .funs = funs(paste0('set', .)))

#>    set c1 c2
#> 1 set1  a  b
#> 2 set1  1  2
#> 3 set2  a  b
#> 4 set2  1  2
```

Created on 2018-09-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this in base R (extensible for n number of data frames)...

```
#### Create data ####
# Create data frames
df1 <- data.frame(c1 = c(1:5), c2 = c(5:1))
df2 <- data.frame(c1 = c(6:10), c2 = c(10:6))

# Create a list of data frames
df_list <- list(df1, df2)

# Create set-mapping (df1 == set1 etc)
df_set <- list('set1', 'set2')


#### Concatenate all data frames into 1 data frame ####
df_result <- df_list %>% Map(function(df, set_name) { 
    # For each dataframe, we add the corresponding set identifier
    df$c3 <- set_name 
    return(df)}, ., df_set) %>% 
    # Loop through list and rbind each encountered dataframe
    Reduce(function(df_1, df_2) rbind(df_1, df_2))
```